# Perl Script help outputting to file

Tags: perl

I have the script below that I need to output to a file, like perl.txt instead of displaying in the terminal window.  This is my first time with perl and can't quite get that part if anyone could offer any advice that would be great.

```
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

foreach my $key (sort keys %ENV) {
print "\$ENV{$key} = $ENV{$key}<br/>\n";
}

exit;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Do you want to create a perl script that runs directly from the command line?

Comment: You could use shell redirection without even knowing a thing about Perl. Or you could spend 30 minutes with `perldoc perlintro`; file manipulation is discussed in that document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file and pass its file-descriptor to `print`.

```
open(my $out, ">", "perl.txt") or die "perl.txt: $!";

print $out "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

foreach my $key (sort keys %ENV) {
    print $out "\$ENV{$key} = $ENV{$key}<br/>\n";
}

close($out) or die "perl.txt: $!";
```

Note there's no comma after `$out` in the `print` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This helps tons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial: [Writing to files with Perl](http://perlmaven.com/writing-to-files-with-perl).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# First open a file in write mode
open my $output, '>', 'perl.txt' or die "Can't open file to write: $!";

# use the filehandle with print to write in file instead of printing on terminal
print $output "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

foreach my $key (sort keys %ENV)
{
    print $output "\$ENV{$key} = $ENV{$key}<br/>\n";
}
# close the open file
close $output;
```